# Plain Old Data types with private members?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is Demo a POD type in C++03?

```
struct Demo
{
     private:
       int x;
       int y;
};
```

C++03, §9p4:

> A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor.

After reading [Steve Jessop's post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/146589/54262), I believe Demo is a non-POD because the members are private. However the Standard doesn't say anything about the relation between POD types and access modifiers.

In C++0x Demo is POD because §9p9 (n3126) says:

> A POD struct is a class that is **both a trivial class and a standard-layout class**, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).

Demo is trivial<sup>1</sup> as well as a standard-layout class so it is a POD. Is my interpretation correct?

<sub><sup>1</sup> A trivial class is a class that has a trivial default constructor (12.1) and is trivially copyable. [9p5, n3126]</sub>

Comment: I'd agree that it's POD. It seems that parts of the definition are contradicting each other in that an aggregate can't have private members, but then nothing notes private members elsewhere. Whether the members are public or private will not affect default compare and copy construction, so I'd agree that it's trivial and therefore POD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++03, it's definitely *not* a POD. According to §9/4, "A *POD-struct* is an aggregate class ...", and according to §8.5.1/1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3)."

Under C++0x, at least as of N3090/3092, I believe it *is* a POD. These require only that all non-static members have the same access, not that the access is necessarily public. This is to fix a problem that I believe I was the first to point out -- in C++98/03, a vacuous access specifier leads to a problem:

```
struct x { 
    int a;
public:
    int b;
public:
   int c;
};
```

This fits the requirements of a POD struct -- but the standard still gives permission for the relative positions of `b` and `c` to be swapped because of the intervening access specifier. As a result, being a POD struct doesn't provide the layout guarantees that were intended to ensure compatibility with C structs (for the obvious example).

Comment: Lol, I just wrote that exact same example at the same time as you.

Comment: … and I should've RTFM'd, C++0x has pushed C++03 out of my head already :vP . +1

Comment: Thanks!! How could I miss `§8.5.1/1:`? Anyways my interpretation was correct. `;-)`

Comment: @Potatoswatter: there's one difference between the examples we gave. There's also the requirement that a pointer to a POD struct, suitably converted, points to the first member of the struct -- so the first two members cann't be rearranged, even with an intervening access specifier. The second and third can be though...

Comment: @Prasoon: It's often missed. For example see: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_frm/thread/1f21a3731a645cab/3f68c6bedded3ce5. Note that Francis Glassborrow is (and I believe was at the time) the C++ standard committee's "Principle UK Expert"; I'm pretty sure his initial opinion reflected that of the committee as a whole at the time.

Comment: And now I say : "Jerry Coffin is a very smart guy" :-)

Comment: @Prasoon: It may be less "smart" than "argumentative". When "everybody knows" something is true, it's almost automatic that some part of me wants to prove them wrong. I try to keep that tendency under control, but...

Comment: @Jerry: he he. :-) Good stuff.

Answer (score 4):

From C++11 on, the easiest by far is to ask the compiler with [std::is_pod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_pod/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Demo
{
     private:
       int x;
       int y;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_pod<Demo>::value << std::endl;
}
```

> true